# Cannot create index in Azure DocumentDb with Mongodb protocol

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Now I know that the Unique Index is not supported in DocumentDb, but why I cannot create a normal index using createIndex()? In mongo shell:

```
> db.product.createIndex({itemId:1})
{ "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 1 }
```

but the collection seems unchange:

```
> db.product.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_1",
    "ns" : "admin.product"
}
]
```

I also find Mongodb API Compatibility slide [here](https://www.slideshare.net/aliuy/azure-documentdb-overview). It told us that we can use createIndex function in mongodb to create non-unique index. Does anybody could tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, DocumentDB with API for MongoDB automatically indexes all properties to reduce the setup complexity. We plan to release creating / updating indexes in the next couple releases.

Comment: Is there any new info about when this feature will be supported?

Answer (score 1):

I think indexes are not supported at the moment (27/02/2017). Hopefully, future releases will support them.

Comment: but how can you explain the slide?

Comment: @Mike Probably they just listed features available in MongoDB.

Comment: can you provide a url that declares this to be truth? can you supply a command that would create an index?