# MongoDB Indexes.CreateOneAsync Exception using Azure DocumentDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-indexes

I'm trying to create multiple unique indexes using c# MongoDB driver connecting to Azure DocumentDB instance, but I'm receiving the following exception when trying to create the second unique index:

MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command createIndexes failed: Message: {"Errors":["The number of unique keys cannot be greater than 1."]}

I can't seem to find any documentation regarding the number of unique keys for Azure DocumentDB collection. Note that this exception does not occur when using actual MongoDB instance.

```
var keys = Builders<ProductEntity>.IndexKeys.Ascending(p => p.UPC);
var options = new CreateIndexOptions<ProductEntity>() { Name = "UX_UPC", Unique = true, Sparse = true };
var result = await _collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(keys, options);

keys = Builders<ProductEntity>.IndexKeys.Ascending(p => p.Manufacturer).Ascending(p => p.MPN);
options = new CreateIndexOptions<ProductEntity>() { Name = "UX_Manufacturer_MPN", Unique = true, Sparse = true };
result = await _collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(keys, options);

public class ProductEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UPC { get; set; }
    public string MPN { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please share the definition of the class ``ProductEntity``, we will reproduce the issue based on your code.

Comment: Hi Fred, I added the class definition as you requested. Please let me know if you need anymore information to reproduce the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-api-for-mongodb-now-generally-available/), we could find it does not support for **Unique indexes** currently.

> General availability is just the beginning for all the features and improvements we have in stored for DocumentDB: API for MongoDB. In the near future, we will be releasing support for Unique indexes and  a couple major performance improvements.

This thread discussed [Cannot create index in Azure DocumentDb with Mongodb protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480874/cannot-create-index-in-azure-documentdb-with-mongodb-protocol), you could refer to it.