# Geospatial index querying doesn't work on Azure CosmosDB (DocumentDB) using the Mongo API

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure CosmosDB with a collection `restaurants` where a field `geoJSON` specifies the location of a restaurant in geoJSON format. I am using the MongoDB API to access this.

When I log into the DB using the mongo shell, I am able to see all the documents using `db.restaurants.find()`. I created a 2dsphere geospatial index using `db.restaurants.createIndex( {geoJSON: "2dsphere"})`.

output:

```
{
    "_t" : "CreateIndexesResponse",
    "ok" : 1,
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 4
}
```

However, upon running `db.restaurants.getIndexes()`, I still see only three indexes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480874/cannot-create-index-in-azure-documentdb-with-mongodb-protocol) question says that indexing is not allowed. Is this still the case?

Furthermore, there seems to be an index called

```
{
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "DocumentDBDefaultIndex" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "DocumentDBDefaultIndex_2dsphere",
            "ns" : "<redacted>"
}
```

,but executing a geospatial query returns nothing.

```
db.restautants.find({DocumentDBDefaultIndex: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [24.9430111, 60.166608]}, $maxDistance: 1000}}})
```

How can I execute geospatial queries against this index using the mongo shell? Is this a bug in CosmosDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side. For a quick way, I use [MongoChef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-mongochef) with the Azure Cosmos DB. Based on my test, `db.brucetest1.createIndex({loc:"2dsphere"})` could not be applied to the collection. Moreover, I found DocumentDB automatically creates a 2dsphere index on the location field `DocumentDBDefaultIndex`, then I drop my documents, and insert the documents as follows:

```html
db.brucetest.insertMany([
   {DocumentDBDefaultIndex : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] },name: "Central Park",category : "Parks"},
   {DocumentDBDefaultIndex : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.88, 40.78 ] },name: "La Guardia Airport",category : "Airport"}
])
```

With the following query, I could encounter your issue:

```
db.brucetest.find({DocumentDBDefaultIndex:{$near:{$geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[-73.88, 40.78]}}}})
```

Based on the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480874/cannot-create-index-in-azure-documentdb-with-mongodb-protocol) your mentioned, I assumed that the creating/updating index and Geospatial indexes querying features have not been implemented in the MongoDB Compatibility layer of Azure CosmosDB. Moreover, you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) or wait for these features released.

Comment: Thanks. I just decided to go with the native DocumentDB API in my application. There is a learning curve to it, so it's slowing me down. I hope it gets added quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Geospatial IS currently supported with the MongoDB API.  Please see the [Geospatial operators section here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#operators).